# Modulo by zero error when specifically excluded

Tags: python, modulo

I wrote a prime checker program that checks the remainder up to the square root of a number. I specifically removed modulo with 1 and 0 the program still returns the aforementioned error. Here's the program:

```
def primeCheck(n):
    x = math.floor(math.sqrt(n))
    for i in range(x):
        if (n != 1) and (n != 0):
            if n%i == 0:
                return False
    return True
```

It works ok with all integers but 2.

`primeCheck(2)`

`x = 1`

`i in range(1)` → `0`

Thus the `if` statement in line four returns `False` but it still returns an error.

Comment: Because `if (n != 1) and (n != 0):` isn't using `i`, it is using `n`.

Comment: Debug your code and you'll better understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three problems:

1. Deal specifically with the case of `n` being less than 2.
2. You need to discount `i` being `0` and `1`.
3. You need to *include* the rounded down square root of the number (else you'll incorrectly report prime square numbers - e.g. 49 - as prime).

(2) and (3) are solved by writing

`for i in range(2, 1 + math.floor(math.sqrt(n))):`

and dropping the errant check `if (n != 1) and (n != 0):`.

Comment: Holy shit I'm dumb. I don't know why i checked n... Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

In `n % i`, it is not `n` that must not be zero, it is `i`.

Checking `n != 0` is useless in this case, you need to check `i != 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
def primeCheck(n):
        x = math.floor(math.sqrt(n))
        if (n <= 1):
            return False
        for i in range(2,x+1):
            if n%i == 0:
                return False
        return True
```

Comment: That incorrectly reports 0 and 1 as primes. And the `if (n != 1) and (n != 0):` doesn't really do much here.

Comment: thats why i wrote it will work for n>=2. And you are right we can drop the the if statement as it will never be the case. Or we can change it to handel 0 and 1.